# umask changes to 0002 after cd

Tags: bash, umask

I've noticed an odd behavior on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system. This is my first experience with Ubuntu; previously I used Fedora and never had this problem.

I have set my umask in .bashrc to 0027. But it automatically changes to 0002 every time I cd into another directory. It doesn't matter what directory I go in to; every directory change results in the umask changing.

```
bbrown@cs:~$ umask
0027
bbrown@cs:~$ cd /
bbrown@cs:/$ umask
0002
bbrown@cs:/$ umask 027
bbrown@cs:/$ cd /var/log
bbrown@cs:/var/log$ umask
0002
```

It even happens if I just use `cd` without a directory:

```
bbrown@cs:/var/log$ cd
bbrown@cs:~$ umask 027
bbrown@cs:~$ umask
0027
bbrown@cs:~$ cd
bbrown@cs:~$ umask
0002
```

I've searched through some other discussion boards. A similar question was [asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995894/umask-setting-changes-after-cd) with no resolution.

I have no special ACLs on any of these directories.

```
bbrown@cs:/var/log$ getfacl /
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

bbrown@cs:/var/log$ getfacl /var/log
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: usr/bin
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Filesystems are ext4 with no ACL mounting options:

```
bbrown@cs:/var/log$ more /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/vg0-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/vda1 during installation
UUID=0da490ac-183d-45cd-a490-5d7ac3663337 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg0-export /export         ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg0-home /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg0-var /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg0-mysql /var/lib/mysql  ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg0-pgsql /var/lib/postgresql ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg0-swap none            swap    sw              0       0
```

The csh does not exhibit this behavior; it's bash only as far as I can tell.

What's going on and how do I disable this?

### Update

I copied bash from my Fedora 13 system and put it in my home directory. That version does not exhibit the problem.

```
bbrown@cs:~$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
bbrown@cs:~$ ls -l /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 955024 Apr  3 08:58 /bin/bash
bbrown@cs:~$ ls -l ./bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bbrown bbrown 904664 Sep 11 13:02 ./bash
bbrown@cs:~$ ./bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.7(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
bbrown@cs:~$ exec ./bash
bbrown@cs:~$ umask
0027
bbrown@cs:~$ cd /
bbrown@cs:/$ umask
0027
```

As requested, here's the output of `type cd`:

```
bbrown@cs:~$ type cd
cd is a function
cd () 
{ 
    if builtin cd "$@"; then
        [[ -n "${rvm_current_rvmrc:-}" && "$*" == "." ]] && rvm_current_rvmrc="" || true;
        __rvm_do_with_env_before;
        __rvm_project_rvmrc;
        __rvm_after_cd;
        __rvm_do_with_env_after;
        return 0;
    else
        return $?;
    fi
}
```

That's telling. RVM has taken control of the `cd` command. That's annoying, but it certainly explains what's going on.

Comment: Just to get the obvious out of the way: `type cd`?

Comment: Do you have a `.bash_profile` or a `.bash_login` file present? `.profile` won't be read in this case.

Comment: @jw013: Updated with `cd` only.

Comment: @ire_and_curses You're right; I actually use a .bashrc

Comment: @BarryBrown I meant to post the output of `type cd`.

Comment: Oh! That's interesting. Something that RVM has usurped.

Answer (score 5):

`cd` doesn't change the umask. Either you've overloaded `cd`, or you have a pre- or post-command hook.

Check that `cd` hasn't been overloaded by running `type cd`. This will show you whether it's a “shell builtin” (good) or an alias or function (suspicious).

Run `echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"` to see if you have a post-command hook (bash evaluates the value of this variable before displaying each prompt). Also check for a debug trap which is executed before each command with `trap -p DEBUG`.

Comment: Yup, that's it exactly. I didn't realize that RVM had overridden cd. Now I need to figure out how to restore things to the way they should be.